# jQuery update select ID with row insert

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, select

I am working through a dynamic table row insert challenge and am looking to clone a row, insert it before the row specified by my insert button, and update the id of each element so I can later incorporate some on change behavior.  I've provided a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/6y18mho8/6/

The relevant jquery code is below and while it goes through and updates the ID for an "input" field it seems to ignore my "select" dropdown boxes.  What is causing this behavior?

```
$(document).on('click', 'button.insertbutton', function () {
var rowCount = $('#orderDetail tr').length;
$(this).closest('tr').before($(this).closest('tr').clone());
$(this).closest('tr').find('input','select').each(function() {
    $(this).attr({
        'id': function(_,id) {
            var regex = /[a-zA-Z]+/
            return id.match(regex) + rowCount },
        'value': '',
    })
})

return true;
```

});

As you can see in the fiddle the add and insert buttons work, the rows clone properly, and the ID for the text input fields update properly.  However the id's for the select items don't update. Any help would be much appreciated.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6y18mho8/6/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your are using wrong the jquery find (in order to select all the inputs and all the select items):

You should do:

```
 $("tr:last").clone().find('input, select').each(function() {
```

Fiddle working: http://jsfiddle.net/6y18mho8/8/

Comment: Awesome.  I swear I had tried that but must have been something else wrong as well.  Thank you. Answer accepted